# OpenModelica cannot run FMU?

Tags: modelica, openmodelica, fmi

I have created a model in OpenModelica using some simple blocks and equations:

```
block ZapuniInterpolation
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput tableInput(start=190) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-68, 20}, extent = {{-20, -20}, {20, 20}}, rotation = 0), iconTransformation(origin = {-68, 20}, extent = {{-20, -20}, {20, 20}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput sineGainInput(start=1) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-68, -20}, extent = {{-20, -20}, {20, 20}}, rotation = 0), iconTransformation(origin = {-68, -20}, extent = {{-20, -20}, {20, 20}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealOutput output1 annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {22, 20}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0), iconTransformation(origin = {22, 20}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealOutput output2 annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {42, 20}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0), iconTransformation(origin = {42, 20}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealOutput output3 annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {62, 20}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0), iconTransformation(origin = {62, 20}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput alpha(start=0) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-8,-20}, extent = {{-20, -20}, {20, 20}}, rotation = 0), iconTransformation(origin = {-8,-20}, extent = {{-20, -20}, {20, 20}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput beta(start=0) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {22, -20}, extent = {{-20, -20}, {20, 20}}, rotation = 0), iconTransformation(origin = {22, -20}, extent = {{-20, -20}, {20, 20}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput gamma(start=0) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {52, -20}, extent = {{-20, -20}, {20, 20}}, rotation = 0), iconTransformation(origin = {52, -20}, extent = {{-20, -20}, {20, 20}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput sineFrequency(start = 1) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-38, -20}, extent = {{-20, -20}, {20, 20}}, rotation = 0), iconTransformation(origin = {-38, -20}, extent = {{-20, -20}, {20, 20}}, rotation = 0)));
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
protected
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
  import PI = Modelica.Constants.pi;
// -------------  
  Modelica.Blocks.Tables.CombiTable1Ds modelDef(table = [180.0, 0.0, 0.125639618, 0.122496368, 0.152595123, 1.30134654, 7.03518772, 10.1638193, 11.777113, 12.5243101, 21.683424, 27.5360508, 34.4655838, 34.1353836, -0.000156808334, 0.000567958435, -6.16513252e-06, 5.07716331e-05, 0.000295116516, -0.00226303029, 1.72715359e-05, -2.76345825e-05, -0.000384722595, -1.60172176e-05, 2.38217144e-05, 8.43528748e-06, 2.26263523e-05, -0.0392020416, -0.0412239838, 0.000444312775, -0.00735736036, 0.083243988, 0.00416324186, 0.00528137589, -0.012360487, 1.24845228e-05, -0.196934738, 6.53376694e-05, -7.1772345e-07, -0.047993618; 
  182.5, 0.0, 0.12338031, 0.121614441, 0.152516403, 1.28446889, 7.03372765, 10.160368, 11.7592869, 12.5243101, 24.4601326, 27.5334625, 34.4655838, 32.8034935, -0.000155028641, 0.000569061768, -1.06752777e-05, 4.43576736e-05, 0.000292540131, -0.00226327395, 1.87270737e-05, -2.94425335e-05, -0.000384721771, -1.95333481e-05, 2.38186722e-05, 8.43502998e-06, 2.18605156e-05, -0.038757122, -0.0399122047, 0.000745555359, -0.00661621618, 0.080380722, 0.00384176278, 0.00474613094, -0.010696907, 1.03946018e-05, -0.187355469, 0.000304825897, -3.04758026e-07, -0.0856405334; 
  185.0, 0.0, 0.121165268, 0.120708992, 0.152441833, 1.26705885, 7.03220701, 10.1565781, 11.7394562, 12.5243101, 26.2911625, 27.5308762, 34.4655838, 33.3992195, -0.000153284882, 0.000568685425, -4.0209774e-05, 3.89236832e-05, 0.000290123566, -0.00226349735, 2.0346014e-05, -3.14919395e-05, -0.000384720856, -2.75364189e-05, 2.39696522e-05, 8.43503952e-06, 1.46955872e-05, -0.0383211823, -0.0385091896, 0.00271969485, -0.00597921848, 0.0775424423, 0.00357709074, 0.00436138248, -0.00955755329, 8.97015572e-06, -0.137678406, 0.000970456665, -8.64766174e-07, -0.156308731; 
  187.5, 0.0, 0.118988342, 0.119786552, 0.152369507, 1.24918771, 7.0306282, 10.1524391, 11.7177658, 12.5243092, 26.049839, 27.5282478, 34.4655838, 37.3313332, -0.000151576111, 0.000570432922, 2.22414017e-05, 3.42602654e-05, 0.000287870667, -0.00226369929, 2.21327553e-05, -3.37703247e-05, -0.000384719849, -3.28333435e-05, 2.40614624e-05, 8.43494415e-06, 6.49287128e-06, -0.0378939934, -0.0372608452, -0.00145591199, -0.00542455482, 0.074719574, 0.00335672474, 0.00408232164, -0.00875357533, 7.95372009e-06, -0.080245285, 0.000683899231, 4.3715094e-07, -0.196699677; 
  190.0, 0.0, 0.116858894, 0.118837822, 0.152297958, 1.23091626, 7.02899122, 10.1479139, 11.6941319, 12.5243092, 24.9532948, 27.5255089, 34.4655838, 43.7087631, -0.000149901413, 0.000571410095, 8.67566872e-06, 3.02129364e-05, 0.000285783508, -0.00226387715, 2.41047344e-05, -3.62895241e-05, -0.000384718781, -3.62359619e-05, 2.40104408e-05, 8.43495083e-06, 3.14631987e-06, -0.0374753189, -0.0359707489, -0.000549157532, -0.0049361062, 0.0719031982, 0.00317143512, 0.00388165021, -0.00817939949, 7.20596743e-06, -0.0537428932, 0.000341564392, 1.62058945e-07, -0.2088992; 
  195.0, 0.0, 0.112727142, 0.116876053, 0.152152176, 1.19337523, 7.02551937, 10.1374197, 11.639926, 12.5243092, 22.4547005, 27.5198441, 34.4655838, 63.5006485, -0.000146650772, 0.000572308289, 3.85471559e-06, 2.35291004e-05, 0.000282106537, -0.00226414824, 2.87340622e-05, -4.21810608e-05, -0.00038471637, -4.2829483e-05, 2.39550076e-05, 8.43493652e-06, 1.15650666e-06, -0.0366626587, -0.0333576317, -0.00022747081, -0.0041120615, 0.0662582474, 0.0028797617, 0.00365292263, -0.00749141979, 6.22078133e-06, -0.0335395622, 0.00014459668, 7.19030685e-08, -0.2181745; 
  200.0, 0.0, 0.10876281, 0.114828865, 0.151995438, 1.15478432, 7.02172279, 10.1242056, 11.5731678, 12.5243082, 20.1688595, 27.5138836, 34.4655838, 97.7778931, -0.000143526184, 0.000572750549, 2.4388926e-06, 1.82274666e-05, 0.000279082581, -0.00226427436, 3.46423569e-05, -4.95841827e-05, -0.000384713623, -5.03695107e-05, 2.39311123e-05, 8.4349184e-06, 1.23468935e-06, -0.0358815079, -0.030764555, -0.000133495087, -0.00343931985, 0.0605537033, 0.00266271996, 0.00360132694, -0.00721686459, 5.66029549e-06, -0.0255758495, 8.98340149e-05, 4.8260746e-08, -0.220523834]) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-18, 20}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
  Real[13] omega2 = {modelDef.y[1], modelDef.y[2], modelDef.y[3], modelDef.y[4], modelDef.y[5], modelDef.y[6], modelDef.y[7], modelDef.y[8], modelDef.y[9], modelDef.y[10], modelDef.y[11], modelDef.y[12], modelDef.y[13]};
  // -------------
  Real[13] Ba = {modelDef.y[14], modelDef.y[15], modelDef.y[16], modelDef.y[17], modelDef.y[18], modelDef.y[19], modelDef.y[20], modelDef.y[21], modelDef.y[22], modelDef.y[23], modelDef.y[24], modelDef.y[25], modelDef.y[26]};
  // -------------
  Real[13] Ca = {modelDef.y[27], modelDef.y[28], modelDef.y[29], modelDef.y[30], modelDef.y[31], modelDef.y[32], modelDef.y[33], modelDef.y[34], modelDef.y[35], modelDef.y[36], modelDef.y[37], modelDef.y[38], modelDef.y[39]};
  // -------------
  Real[13] damping = beta * omega2 + gamma * sqrt(omega2) .+ alpha;
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
  Real [1] ssu "input vector";
  Real [3] ssy = {output1, output2, output3}"output vector";
  Real [26] ssx "state vector";
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
  // -------------
  Real[26, 26] ssA = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0; 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0; 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0; 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0; 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0; 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0; 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0; 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0; 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0; 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0; 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0; 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0; 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1; 
-omega2[1], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -damping[1], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0; 
0, -omega2[2], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -damping[2], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0; 
0, 0, -omega2[3], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -damping[3], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0; 
0, 0, 0, -omega2[4], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -damping[4], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0; 
0, 0, 0, 0, -omega2[5], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -damping[5], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0; 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -omega2[6], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -damping[6], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0; 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -omega2[7], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -damping[7], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0; 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -omega2[8], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -damping[8], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0; 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -omega2[9], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -damping[9], 0, 0, 0, 0; 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -omega2[10], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -damping[10], 0, 0, 0; 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -omega2[11], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -damping[11], 0, 0; 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -omega2[12], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -damping[12], 0; 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -omega2[13], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -damping[13]];
  // ------------
  Real[26, 1] ssB = [0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; Ba[1]; Ba[2]; Ba[3]; Ba[4]; Ba[5]; Ba[6]; Ba[7]; Ba[8]; Ba[9]; Ba[10]; Ba[11]; Ba[12]; Ba[13]];
  // ------------
  Real[3, 26] ssC = [Ca[1], Ca[2], Ca[3], Ca[4], Ca[5], Ca[6], Ca[7], Ca[8], Ca[9], Ca[10], Ca[11], Ca[12], Ca[13], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0; 
  Ba[1], Ba[2], Ba[3], Ba[4], Ba[5], Ba[6], Ba[7], Ba[8], Ba[9], Ba[10], Ba[11], Ba[12], Ba[13], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0; 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, Ba[1], Ba[2], Ba[3], Ba[4], Ba[5], Ba[6], Ba[7], Ba[8], Ba[9], Ba[10], Ba[11], Ba[12], Ba[13]];
  // -----------
  Real[3, 1] ssD = [0; 0; 0];
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
initial equation
  ssx = fill(0, 26);
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
equation
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
  connect(modelDef.u, tableInput) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-30, 20}, {-68, 20}}, color = {0, 0, 127}));
  der(ssx) = ssA * ssx + ssB * ssu;
  ssy = ssC * ssx + ssD * ssu;
  ssu = {sineGainInput *sin(2*PI*sineFrequency*time)};
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
  annotation(
    uses(Modelica(version = "3.2.3")));
end ZapuniInterpolation;
```

Now I exported the model to an FMU using OpenModelica, using version 2.0 and Model Exchange - Co Simulation. When I import this FMU in another model and attach simple inputs and outputs, like:

```
model importZapuniFMUtest
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput alpha(start=0) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-80, 80}, extent = {{-20, -20}, {20, 20}}, rotation = 0), iconTransformation(origin = {-80, 80}, extent = {{-20, -20}, {20, 20}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput beta(start=0) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-80, 50}, extent = {{-20, -20}, {20, 20}}, rotation = 0), iconTransformation(origin = {-80, 50}, extent = {{-20, -20}, {20, 20}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput gamma(start=0) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-80, 20}, extent = {{-20, -20}, {20, 20}}, rotation = 0), iconTransformation(origin = {-80, 20}, extent = {{-20, -20}, {20, 20}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput Length(start=190) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-80, -80}, extent = {{-20, -20}, {20, 20}}, rotation = 0), iconTransformation(origin = {-80, -80}, extent = {{-20, -20}, {20, 20}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput Amplitude(start=1) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-80, -50}, extent = {{-20, -20}, {20, 20}}, rotation = 0), iconTransformation(origin = {-80, -50}, extent = {{-20, -20}, {20, 20}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput Frequency(start=1) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-80, -20}, extent = {{-20, -20}, {20, 20}}, rotation = 0), iconTransformation(origin = {-80, -20}, extent = {{-20, -20}, {20, 20}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealOutput Y1 annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {70, 50}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0), iconTransformation(origin = {70, 50}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealOutput Y2 annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {70, 30}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0), iconTransformation(origin = {70, 30}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealOutput Y3 annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {70, 10}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0), iconTransformation(origin = {70, 10}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  ZapuniInterpolation_me_FMU zapuniInterpolation annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {10, 10}, extent = {{-30, -30}, {30, 30}}, rotation = 0)));
equation
  connect(zapuniInterpolation.alpha, alpha) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-24, 32}, {-30, 32}, {-30, 80}, {-80, 80}, {-80, 80}}, color = {0, 0, 127}));
  connect(zapuniInterpolation.beta, beta) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-24, 24}, {-40, 24}, {-40, 50}, {-80, 50}, {-80, 50}}, color = {0, 0, 127}));
  connect(zapuniInterpolation.gamma, gamma) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-24, 16}, {-50, 16}, {-50, 20}, {-80, 20}, {-80, 20}}, color = {0, 0, 127}));
  connect(zapuniInterpolation.sineFrequency, Frequency) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-24, 8}, {-50, 8}, {-50, -20}, {-80, -20}, {-80, -20}}, color = {0, 0, 127}));
  connect(zapuniInterpolation.sineGainInput, Amplitude) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-24, 0}, {-40, 0}, {-40, -50}, {-80, -50}, {-80, -50}}, color = {0, 0, 127}));
  connect(zapuniInterpolation.tableInput, Length) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-24, -6}, {-30, -6}, {-30, -80}, {-80, -80}, {-80, -80}}, color = {0, 0, 127}));
  connect(zapuniInterpolation.output1, Y1) annotation(
    Line(points = {{44, 32}, {50, 32}, {50, 50}, {70, 50}, {70, 50}}, color = {0, 0, 127}));
  connect(zapuniInterpolation.output2, Y2) annotation(
    Line(points = {{44, 24}, {52, 24}, {52, 30}, {70, 30}, {70, 30}}, color = {0, 0, 127}));
  connect(zapuniInterpolation.output3, Y3) annotation(
    Line(points = {{44, 16}, {50, 16}, {50, 10}, {70, 10}, {70, 10}}, color = {0, 0, 127}));

annotation(
    uses(Modelica(version = "3.2.3")));
end importZapuniFMUtest;
```

I get the following error:

> [1] 13:28:34 Translation Error [ZapuniInterpolation_me_FMU: 1360:7-1360:39]: Operator reinit may only be used in the body of a when equation.

I have no idea what I have done wrong, since the initial model runs just fine in OpenModelica, I can change all of the inputs etc but the exported model does not work.

Comment: See: https://trac.openmodelica.org/OpenModelica/ticket/5621
It might work if you use the old front-end: Options->Tools->Simulation->Enable old frontend for code generation.

Comment: @AdrianPop That indeed solves the problem! But why? Do you have any clue?

Comment: The old front-end doesn't check if reinit is used in algorithm sections. Modelica Spec doesn't allow it and the new frontend which is the default lately checks it and generates that error.

Comment: I read something like that when looking in to your suggestion. But why does OpenModelica itself generate a FMU that violates it's own rules?

Comment: It would be very much apreciated if OpenModelica would join the FMI Cross-Check https://github.com/modelica/fmi-cross-check to get rid of such problems in the future

Comment: @ChristianBertsch: is in the plan to do so, we have been in there but then the repo moved and something got lost.

Comment: @jvandeweg: OpenModelica generates an FMU that can be used anywhere (for that specific platform). The problem with the import is that it generates a Modelica model as a wrapper for the FMU and that model is not really correct. Importing FMUs in Modelica model in a portable way is not really clear, the Modelica Association had countless discussions about this and didn't reach too much of a conclusion so each tool vendors does their own FMU import in specific non-portable ways. We are working on a better way to support FMU imports via OMSimulator.

Comment: @AdrianPop Thanks for your elaborate reply! I can definitely understand that it is not that easy to come up with a general solution. For now I will just use the old frontend and wait for new updates to come.

Comment: @AdrianPop : I just wrote a comment to https://github.com/modelica/ModelicaSpecification/issues/1727 suggesting to spend effort in a portable FMI 3.0 support especially for the coming FMI 3.0.